# Extend function args with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Hi with the below example, i'm unclear as to why the compiler isn't complaining when the additional argument of foo is passed *without* a generic containing that property being passed to the function call. Is this expected behaviour ?

Ideally i would like to only allow additional arguments when they are passed as a Generic to the function call, is this possible?

```js
type Props<ExtraArgs> = {
    isOpen: boolean
} & ExtraArgs


const myFunc = <ExtraArgs>(props: Props<ExtraArgs>) => { }


myFunc({ isOpen: true, foo: 'xxx' })

// ☝ Im not passing <ExtraArgs> as a generic containing { foo: string } so why isnt the compiler complaining about the extra arg?
```

Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=132#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwDwFEAew4EMCCcA5sgHxQC8UA3gFBQNQCWyA8pAHYBcUARgggA2EXB1oBfKADIoWHAWLJaygMYIOyYFAC2IAGIBXDispQM2PIRKkAFGEQoe8JGjmXFpAJSVy1KOOVaXUNjGz8WdghuKBwDCAAaKAAzAR4AckxMtP9PZQB6PKhAXDJAHg3AH-2oAEltKA4ELTBcZGQmDiIzNwVrKCaeqCIoiDgmEzUOYFxW1va-FIQeTWG2-yhkBCgAdwALEGZkcZit6DVtMCZhOCgTsEFJjmme-gMtYCOoCAtcHuIAfiA) to the same example in the TS playground

Comment: Since you pass an object that has `isOpen` property and the value is a boolean, then that satisfies the interface. The compiler would stop you trying to get `props.foo` when inside the function, since the interface doesn't have that property.

Comment: The thing is, this only seems to happen when i extend my `Props` type with `ExtraArgs` ie `& ExtraArgs`

Comment: If you don't specify generic type explicitly it is inferred from passed parameter. (`Props<{isOpen: true, foo: string}` in this case)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlekseyL. in this example, i want the compiler to complain when the function is called with an argument is passed that doesnt exist in the type *unless* it is passed in as a generic, so in this case 


myFunc<{foo: string}>({ isOpen: true, foo: 'xxx' })

Comment: But why, what's the point?

Comment: @AlekseyL. i'm building a UI lib and want to give users a nice TS experience where i can. The compiler *should* give the user feedback if they have passed an incorrect  argument. Isn't that one of the main benefits of TS?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passing object with extra parameters. Think about it. You'll only make users' life harder if you'll make them specify type explicitly